# How to calculate shipping cost based off by weight and distance?

Tags: c++

I am writing a package shipping program in my c++ class. I am supposed to prompt the user for weight, then prompt them for the distance the package is going, then calculate the shipping. I am struggling with calculating shipping. The shipping rate is a flat rate of $1.10 per each 500 miles or portion thereof, so what could I write that calculates the shipping of a package based off the distance and rate above?

```cpp
#include<iostream>
        
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;
        
double weight, distance;
const double twoOrLess = 1.10;
const double twoToSix = 2.20;
const double sixToTen = 3.70;
const double tenToTwenty = 4.80;
        
int main()
{
    cout << "Welcome to Shippers R Us!" << endl 
         << "------------------------"  << endl;
        
    do
    {
        cout << "Package weight(in Kg, 0 to end): ";
        cin >> weight;
        
        while (weight < 0 || weight > 3000)
        {
            if (weight == 0)
            {
                break;
            }
            else if (weight < 0)
            {
                cout << "weight must be greater than zero." << endl;
                cout << "------------------------" << endl;
                cout << "Package weight(in Kg, 0 to end): ";
                cin  >> weight;
            }
            else if (weight > 20)
            {
                cout << "We do not ship iteams weighing more than 20 kilograms." << endl;
                cout << "------------------------" << endl;
                cout << "Package weight(in Kg, 0 to end): ";
                cin >> weight;
            }
        }
    
        if (weight == 0)
        {
            break;
        }
    
        cout << "Distance(in miles): ";
        cin >> distance;
    
        while (distance < 10 || distance > 3000)
        {
            if (distance < 10)
            {
                cout << "Distance must be between 10 and 3,000 miles." <<
                endl << "Distance(in miles): ";
                cin >> distance;
            }
        }
        // This is where I need to calculate shipping
    } while (weight != 0);
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: You can use a percentage here. If the user enters `300` miles then, `(300 / 500) * 1.10` will give you `$0.66` to ship their package. If they enter `1000` miles then, `(1000 / 500) * 1.10` will give you `$2.20` to ship their package.

Comment: *"I am struggling with calculating shipping."* -- good, you know what to focus on. Now make your **example** code focus on this part. We are not grading your assignment, so we have no need to see your full program. Strip out the fluff I/O. Hardcode example values, such as `double weight = 2.4; // Would be user input` and `double distance = 42.3; // Would  be user input`. How focused does your code become when you get rid of the I/O and error checking?

Comment: But that will not give the same answer if the user enters something like 644? I need it to print the $1.10 price for every 500 miles, so if the user entered 644 I need it to calculate it to be $2.20 for shipping because it is 1.10 for every 500 miles

Comment: That's an interesting question. Is the distance supposed to be handled in blocks of 500? You'll need to make this brutally clear in the question otherwise people will leap to the more obvious solution.

Comment: Anyway, you have a math problem, not a programming problem, at this point, so forget about the code. How would you handle this if you had a pen and a piece of paper and someone shouting numbers at you to process? Start your solution there. It may not be optimal, but it gets you started. You'll find a lot of computer problems can be solved the same way the human would solve them, and often that solution is fast enough.

Comment: Yes the distance is handled in blocks of 500s, so miles between 0 and 500 would equal $1.10 and then miles 501-1000 would equal $2.20 and so on

Comment: The idiotic approach is subtraction in a loop. You can perform integer division and add 1, but you have to guard against the edge cases (eg 500 / 500 +1 = 2. Ooops).

Answer (score 1):

> The shipping rate is $1.10 per 500 miles

I'm not sure if this is what you mean but, you can divide the distance by 500, and then multiply that by the shipping rate, for instance if the distance is 500, that divided by 500 is 1 times 1.10 would be the price.

therefore

```
price = (distance/500)*1.10;
```

Comment: But that will not give the same answer if the user enters something like 644? I need it to print the $1.10 price for every 500 miles, so if the user entered 644 I need it to calculate it to be $2.20 for shipping because it is 1.10 for every 500 miles

Comment: multiplier = (distance-(distance%500))/500;
if(distance%500)
    multiplier = multiplier+1;
price = multiplier * 1.10